# Bash move and rename folders

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bunch of folders like that:

```
Team A - Folder 01/
Team A - Folder 02/
Team B - 14-12-2003 - Folder XX/
Team B - 21-03-2008 - Folder YY/
...
```

With the passing time, this list have became very long and hard to maintain so I want to change the directory tree to something like that:

```
Team A/
    Folder 01/
    Folder 02/
Team B/
    14-12-2003 - Folder XX/
    21-03-2008 - Folder YY/
```

I know that I can use `rename` to batch rename files using regular expressions, but it seems that it can't rename things to subdirectory structure like what I want to achieve.

Any idea of how to achieve that ?

---

Here's the solution I've used, inspired from the solution given by Froggiz

```
#!/bin/bash

#Path with folders to move/rename
Path="/tmp/testmv/"

#Get each folder in original path
for ofolder in ${Path}/*;do

    #replace space by _ to be able to use bash array
    folder=${ofolder// /_}

    #cut string to have only string after last /
    folder=${folder##*/}

    #create an array with _-_ as split delimiter (dash + 2 spaces around)
    cutFoldArr=(${folder/_-_/ })

    #create destination subfolder if not already exist
    mkdir -p "${Path}${cutFoldArr[0]//_/ }"

    #move original folder, to new sub folder destination
    mv "${ofolder}" "${Path}${cutFoldArr[0]//_/ }/${cutFoldArr[1]//_/ }"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the script you want, there only few things i need to notice:

- actually the code create sub folder in destination folder, but dont move files, it just show what it is going to do, to execute the move you need to uncomment the "mv line" (and you can comment the echo line, if you don't want output)
- name in folder with space isn't a good idea in linux, so i changed spaces for undescores, so if you prefer spaces

change

```
${cutFoldArr[0]} & ${cutFoldArr[1]}
```

by

```
${cutFoldArr[0]//_/ } & ${cutFoldArr[1]//_/ }
```

- to call this script, put it in a .sh file, and then bash YOURFILE.sh

  #!bin/bash/

  #Path with original folders

  fromPath="/opt/test/"

  #Destination path

  toPath="/opt/test2/"

  #Create destination path if not already exist

  mkdir -p ${toPath}

  #Get each folder in original path

  for ofolder in ${fromPath}/*;do

  #replace space by _ to be able to use bash array

  folder=${ofolder// /_}

  #cut string to have only string after last /

  folder=${folder##*/}

  #create an array with *-* as split delimiter

  cutFoldArr=(${folder/*-*/ })

  #create destination subfolder if not already exist

  mkdir -p ${toPath}${cutFoldArr[0]}

  #move original folder, to new sub folder destination

  #mv ${ofolder} ${toPath}${cutFoldArr[0]}/${cutFoldArr[1]}

  echo "mv ${ofolder} ${toPath}${cutFoldArr[0]}/${cutFoldArr[1]}"

  done

sorry for the code formating display i didn't found how to display it in a better way.. :P

more info about special bash code:

```
$0                      script name
${0##*/} = $(echo $0 | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev) allstring after last /
${0%/*} = $(echo $0 | sed "s/\/$Path//g")   all string before last /
${0#*/}"                    delete all before first /
${0%/*}"                    delete all after / 
${1%?}                      remove last char
${0:0:1}                    first char
${0/a/b}                    replace first a by b
${0//a/b}                   replace all a by b
(${0//@/ })                 split char @
${0//[[:alpha:]]/X}             replace alpha by X (can be [[:digit:]])
${0//[a-zA-Z]/X}                and it works with reg exp
${0^^}                      to uppercase
${0,,}                      to lowercase
${#0}                       string size
${!var}                     create a dynamic variable
```

with 0 can be change with your variable name

Comment: I'm not responsible for naming folders, so I have to keep spaces in the folder names ... I'm updating my question with the script I've used, inspired from your answer. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your directory structure is consistent, you can script this easy using Bash's `Remove matching pattern`.

From Bash man page:

> ${parameter#word}
>   ${parameter##word}
>
> Remove  matching prefix pattern. 
>   The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname
>   expansion.  If the pattern matches the beginning of the value of
>   parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of
>   parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the # case) or the
>   longest matching pattern (the  ``##''  case) deleted. If parameter is
>   @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional
>   parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If
>   parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern
>   removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and
>   the expansion is the resultant list.

Given your example, if directory Team A - Folder 01 is in `$dir` variable, `echo ${dir#Team\ 01\ -\ }` will change it to `Folder 01` etc.